# save result in the csv file PHP

Tags: php, csv

i am trying to fetch all data from a table and save into a **csv** file.

i did not get any error but it is not creating the csv file with the result as well.

but when i see the output i see that the results is there but why the csv file is not creating for the result!!

PHP code --

```
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `info_contact`');

        if (!$result){
            die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
        }

        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $headers = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
            $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        }
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        if ($fp && $result) {
            header('Content-Type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myCsvFile.csv"');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            fputcsv($fp, $headers);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
            }
            die;
        }
```

**Output** ---

```
id,name,email,message,content,contactTime

34,chris,christoferhansen@gmail.com,"Hi Chris","C:fakepathCoding style.pdf","2015-11-29 19:49:02"

35,Hansen,hansen@yahoo.com,ad,,"2015-11-29 19:52:20"
```

Where is my mistake for not being able to create a cvs file !

Can anyone help me with this please

Answer (score 2):

You script create csv for download. If you have write it to file on server than replace `$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');` with `$fp = fopen('path/to/file.csv', 'w');` and remove all `header` calls